# Admin language does not change

Tags: localisation, settings

I try to change the language localisation of our site to dutch following the documentation at: http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/i18n+Administrator%27s+Guide%3A+Using+CiviCRM+in+your+own+language

I uploaded our language files at sites/all/modules/civicrm/l10n/nl_NL
Now some of the backend interface (settings) shows in dutch.
But the admin menu and for instance event emails are still send in english.

When I change the language on the 4.6 sandbox the whole menu changes.
I already dropped civicrm_domain. What else can I do to get this working using civicrm 4.6.4 / drupal 7.38 ?

Comment: Similar problem. After an update to civiCRM 4.6.11 (Drupal 7.41), civiCRM returned to English. After changing to Dutch and other variables on the localisation settings (admin > settings > localization) i got the message "Changes saved", but they were not saved.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, if you change the language after the installation, the data that has been loaded during installation in the database will not be translated.

I am not aware of an easy way of fixing that but you could use as a start the sql files in civicrm-xxx-l10n.tar.gz and do updates instead of insert.

The issue is known and hopefully will be fixed in CiviCRM 4.7

Comment: Thanx. Is there an jira issue number that you know of?

Comment: It was on our i18n improvements TODO list at Denver Civi Sprint. Just added a new JIRA for it - CRM-17065